# image click replaces image with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

When the user clicks on the image I want to replace the 'input type:image' with a 'iframe' in the same position and the same height. iv tried adding the iframe and setting the display to invisible then visible when clicked but this causes alignment issues

also tried setting display of iframe to none, which looks good at the start but then how do i get it to appear where the map previously was?

```
<script>
        function showIframeMapOnClick() {
            alert("this is a test");
            $("#Image1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $("#iFrameMap").css('visibility', 'visible');
///            $("#iFrameMap").css('visibility', 'block');
        }
</script>

<div id="Contact Us" class="backimage2" style="width:100%;">
        <div id="Fullcontent">
        <div id="thirdPageDiv" class="wrapper whitediv">
        <div>
             <input type="image" ID="Image1" onclick="showIframeMapOnClick();return false" src="/images/mapImage.png" style="float:right; position:relative; width:550px" />
             <iframe id="iFrameMap" src='https:' width='50%' height='400px' style="float:right; position:relative; width:550px; visibility:hidden"/*also tried display:none*/></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="black-header">Contact Us</div><br />
            This House,<br /> 
            This Street,<br /> 
            This Door,<br /> 
            This LetterB,<br /> 
            Please,<br /> 
            Come Again,<br />
            <br />
        </div>
        </div> 
        </div>
```

anyone know how to resolve this?
thanks

Comment: I bet you used `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible`... Try with `display:none` and `display:block` (or `inline`, up to you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Give id to your div,(here its myDiv), and define height & width for it. Inside that use your image.
> When user clicks button, change the content of div, thus the iframe will be shown in same position. Code shown below

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        function showIframeMapOnClick() {
            $("#myDiv").html("<iframe id='iFrameMap' src='https:' width='50%' height='400px' style=''></iframe>");
        }
    </script>

    <div id="Contact Us" class="backimage2" style="width:100%;">
        <div id="Fullcontent">
            <div id="thirdPageDiv" class="wrapper whitediv">
                <div id="myDiv" style="float:right; position:relative; width:550px">
                    <input type="image" ID="Image1" onclick="showIframeMapOnClick();return false" src="/images/mapImage.png"  />
                </div>
                <div class="black-header">Contact Us</div><br />
                This House,<br />
                This Street,<br />
                This Door,<br />
                This LetterB,<br />
                Please,<br />
                Come Again,<br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```